# How can I categorise MySQLi result set?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

How can I change the code below so that I am only echoing each unique '$course' only once?

eg. currently my results look like =

ipswich-11:00-running
ipswich-12:00-flamingo rider
ipswich-14:00-lightning
norwich-13:10-ed is back
norwich-14:05-redrum
norwich-17:05-pickle

but I would like them to look like =

Ipswich

11:00-running
12:00-flamingo rider
14:00-lightning

norwich

13:10-ed is back
14:05-redrum
17:05-pickle

I thought about doing a mysqli query in a for each loop, but surely there is a better way?

My code =

```
<?php //connection block

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);}

$today = date("Ymd");
$query = "SELECT horse, course, time, date FROM dailytips WHERE date = $today ORDER BY course, time"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$today_uk = " " . date("d/m/y");

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{ $rows[] = $row; }

echo "<h2>tips for" .$today_uk. "</h2>";

foreach($rows as $row) 
{ 
$date = $row['date'];
$date = date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));
$horse = $row['horse'];
$time = $row['time'];
$course = $row['course'];

echo  
'<div style= "width:600px; font-family:verdana;">
 <div style="float:left; width:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top10px;">

        '.$row['course']. "-" .$row['time'] . "-" . $row['horse'] .'
 </div>' ;
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close(); 

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could nest a foreeach statement inside another.

so...

```
$query = "SELECT course, FROM dailytips WHERE date = $today ORDER BY course, time";
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{ $rows[] = $row; }

echo "<h2>tips for" .$today_uk. "</h2>";

foreach($rows as $row) {
   $query = "SELECT horse, time, date FROM dailytips WHERE course = $row['course'];
   while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
   { $rowDetail[] = $rowDetails; }

   foreach($rows as $row) { 
       $date = $row['date'];
       $date = date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));
       $horse = $row['horse'];
       $time = $row['time'];
       $course = $row['course'];

       echo  
          '<div style= "width:600px; font-family:verdana;">
          <div style="float:left; width:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top10px;">

          '.$row['course']. "-" .$row['time'] . "-" . $row['horse'] .'
          </div>' ;
      }
   }
```

I would consider putting your results in a table opposed to DIVs as this would seem to fit what you are trying to do much better. Set the table up before the loop and close once the loop has been exited.

Comment: I think the $row in $query is giving me T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE error.